# Windows Phone 7 Emulator - showing/disappearing couple times eventually giving up

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, connect

When i try to launch Windows Phone 7 Emulator directly it is toggling on/off 2-3 times (can see it for like 2-4 sec),

then stopping without giving any error message.
There is only

> "Windows Phone Emulator is doing a complete OS Boot"

somewhere in the middle of appearance.

When i launch it from `Expression Blend 4` it is also toggling `on/off`,

but less frequently and in the middle there is progress bar window stuck always at same place about connecting eventually giving this

> error: http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/7025/errorqu.png

The issue is on:

> Asus 1005PXD (2 weeks old) with Windows 7 SP1 64 bit

Installed my software in that order:

> VS10 Ultimate
>
> VS10 SP1
>
> WP7 SDK
>
> Expression 4 Ultimate (incl. Blend)

Comment: do you have other virtual machines running on your system? Also, WP7 SDK comes with VS10 Express, do you have VS10 Ultimate as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, Intel GMA 3150 which i have in 1005PXD does not support XNA, after installing WP7.1 SDK it was showing proper information.

But still i don't know why i cannot run emulator at all, but it still should be possible to run non-XNA applications.